# Подсветка смежных элементов

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript

Всем доброго времени суток!

Задание таково:

Сделать подсветку(смену стиля/свойства/преступной прошлой жизни) элементов, находящихся рядом с активным(на который навели курсор). Я знаю, что задавал вопрос про таблицу, но это совсем другое.

Но проблема основная не в том, как сделать, а как оптимизировать(основной вопрос после кода)

```js
(function () {//это вспомогательное всё, основное дальше
 "use strict";
 window.FLUENT = {
  all: (arr, clbc, stopIf) => {
   if (arguments.length === 3)
    for (let i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
     if (clbc(arr[i], i) === stopIf)
      return;
    }
   else
    for (let i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
     clbc(arr[i], i);
    }
  },
  pos: (elem, pageXOffset = !0, pageYOffset = !0) => {
   let rect,
   win,
   a = elem;
   if (!a.getClientRects().length) {
    return {
     top: 0,
     left: 0
    };
   }
   rect = a.getBoundingClientRect();
   win = a.ownerDocument.defaultView;
   return {
    top: rect.top + (pageYOffset ? win.pageYOffset : 0),
    left: rect.left + (pageXOffset ? win.pageXOffset : 0)
   };
  },
  uid: () => ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c => (c ^ crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & 15 >> c / 4).toString(16))
 };
})();

/**
будет два новых элемента:
f-cubox
f-cub
**/
(function() {
  "use strict";
  let cubs = {}; //здесь все "кубы" всех "кубоксов"
  class el extends HTMLElement { //создаём класс элемента
    connectedCallback() { //при создании элемента
      let uid = this.parentNode.getAttribute("uid") || FLUENT.uid(), //uid текущего f-cubox
        th = this,
        thPos = {},
        thIndex,
        otherPos = {},
        temp,
        row,
        col,
        out = false,
        over = false,
        setter = s => { //это чтоб не повторять кучу кода по 2 раза
          s === 2 && (
            row[col - 2] && row[col - 2].setAttribute("pos", "d2"),
            row[col - 1] && row[col - 1].setAttribute("pos", "cd"),
            row[col] && row[col].setAttribute("pos", "c2"),
            row[col + 2] && row[col + 2].setAttribute("pos", "d2"),
            row[col + 1] && row[col + 1].setAttribute("pos", "cd"));
          s === 1 && (
            row[col - 1] && row[col - 1].setAttribute("pos", "d1"),
            row[col - 2] && row[col - 2].setAttribute("pos", "cd"),
            row[col] && row[col].setAttribute("pos", "c1"),
            row[col + 2] && row[col + 2].setAttribute("pos", "cd"),
            row[col + 1] && row[col + 1].setAttribute("pos", "d1"));
        };
      if (cubs[uid] === undefined) { //если текущий cubox не получил uid
        th.parentNode.setAttribute("uid", uid); //добавляем его
        cubs[uid] = [];
      }
      cubs[uid].push(th); //после чего добавляем текущий куб(далее=th) в массив
      th.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        if (over) //это чтоб действие не повторялось кучу раз
          return;
        out = false;
        over = true;
        th.setAttribute("pos", "c0"); //ставим на th значение pos для центра
        thPos = FLUENT.pos(th); //запоминаем позицию th
        temp = { //создаём пустой temp
          alltop: [] //здесь будут все позиции кубов по top
        };
        FLUENT.all(cubs[uid], el => {//итерируем массив с кубами текущего кубокса
          otherPos = FLUENT.pos(el);//запоминаем позицию el
          if (temp.alltop.indexOf(otherPos.top) === -1)//если в массиве alltop нет текущего top кубов
            temp.alltop.push(otherPos.top);//то добавляем её
          if (temp[otherPos.top] === undefined) //еси в матррице нет текущей высоты
            temp[otherPos.top] = [el];//то добавляем свойство с именем высота_el и значением массив с el 
          else
            temp[otherPos.top].push(el);//else просто добавляем el к нужному ряду
        });
        temp.alltop.sort((a, b) => a - b); //сортируем список топов по возрастанию
        thIndex = temp.alltop.indexOf(thPos.top); //получаем индекс позиции th по top в массиве top'ов
        if (thIndex - 2 > -1) { //проверка на.. ну понятно же
          row = temp[temp.alltop[thIndex - 2]]; //получаем из матрицы ряд с элементами
          col = temp[thPos.top].indexOf(th);//получаем индекс колонки с th в ряду row
          setter(2);//выполняем второй сценарий в setter
        }
        if (thIndex - 1 > -1) {
          row = temp[temp.alltop[thIndex - 1]];
          col = temp[thPos.top].indexOf(th);
          setter(1);//выполняем первый сценарий в setter

        }
        if (thIndex > -1) {
          row = temp[temp.alltop[thIndex]];
          col = temp[thPos.top].indexOf(th);
          row[col - 2] && row[col - 2].setAttribute("pos", "c2");
          row[col - 1] && row[col - 1].setAttribute("pos", "c1");
          row[col + 2] && row[col + 2].setAttribute("pos", "c2");
          row[col + 1] && row[col + 1].setAttribute("pos", "c1");

        }
        if (thIndex + 1 < temp.alltop.length) {
          row = temp[temp.alltop[thIndex + 1]];
          col = temp[thPos.top].indexOf(th);
          setter(1);
        }
        if (thIndex + 2 < temp.alltop.length) {
          row = temp[temp.alltop[thIndex + 2]];
          col = temp[thPos.top].indexOf(th);
          setter(2);
        }
      });
      th.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {//тут просто очистка всех pos после выхода мыши с элемента
        if (out)
          return;
        out = true;
        over = false;
        cubs[uid].forEach(el => {
          el.setAttribute("pos", "");
        });
      });
    }
  }
  customElements.define("f-cub", el);//ну и добавляем теперь элемент
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

f-cubox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

f-cub {
  cursor: default;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}


/*fluent animation*/

f-cub {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .01);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.60);
  border: 3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transition: all .3s;
}


/*
==========================
d2 || cd || c2 || cd || d2
==========================
cd || d1 || c1 || d1 || cd
==========================
c2 || c1 || c0 || c1 || c2
==========================
cd || d1 || c1 || d1 || cd
==========================
d2 || cd || c2 || cd || d2
==========================
это общий вид матриц с элементами
*/

f-cub[pos=c0],
f-button[sensor]:active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .06);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .03);
}

f-cub[pos=c1] {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .03);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .01);
}

f-cub[pos=c2] {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .02);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
}

f-cub[pos=d1] {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .025);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .65);
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .005);
}

f-cub[pos=d2] {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .01);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

f-cub[pos=cd] {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .015);
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .55);
}
```

```html
<f-cubox>
  <f-cub>a</f-cub>
  <f-cub>b</f-cub>
  <f-cub>c</f-cub>
  <f-cub>d</f-cub>
  <f-cub>e</f-cub>
  <f-cub>f</f-cub>
  <f-cub>g</f-cub>
  <f-cub>h</f-cub>
  <f-cub>i</f-cub>
  <f-cub>j</f-cub>
  <f-cub>k</f-cub>
  <f-cub>l</f-cub>
  <f-cub>m</f-cub>
  <f-cub>n</f-cub>
  <f-cub>o</f-cub>
  <f-cub>p</f-cub>
  <f-cub>q</f-cub>
  <f-cub>r</f-cub>
  <f-cub>s</f-cub>
  <f-cub>t</f-cub>
  <f-cub>u</f-cub>
  <f-cub>v</f-cub>
  <f-cub>w</f-cub>
  <f-cub>x</f-cub>
  <f-cub>y</f-cub>
  <f-cub>z</f-cub>
  <f-cub>0</f-cub>
  <f-cub>1</f-cub>
  <f-cub>2</f-cub>
  <f-cub>3</f-cub>
  <f-cub>4</f-cub>
  <f-cub>5</f-cub>
  <f-cub>6</f-cub>
  <f-cub>7</f-cub>
  <f-cub>8</f-cub>
  <f-cub>9</f-cub>
</f-cubox>
```

Собственно вопрос таков: как оптимизировать кусок кода, отвечающий за создание "матрицы". Ведь я понимаю, что каждый раз при наведении на элемент итерировать и тасовать такую кучу есть очень плохо.